# Trouble with postfix install (timing out from client)

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, smtp

I have just outfitted a basic server (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS /Precise Pangolin) and have installed Postfix and Dovecot, based on the Ubuntu manuals.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Dovecot

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix

Postfix gets mail out of the box to my gmail account, e.g.:

```
sendmail [redacted]@gmail.com < /etc/motd
```

Testing remote access with the open source client for Eudora, I can successfully download email, so Dovecot/POP3 seems to be functioning.

However, I cannot seem to get Eudora to successfully get mail from the client to the box or beyond. Depending on the security/port config I use, it generally times out.

I seem to be able to get access via the local terminal, and remote shells, such as (from a remote server):

```
$ telnet lists.teachers.net 25
Trying 50.56.184.186...
Connected to lists.teachers.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 lists.teachers.net ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo lists.teachers.net
250-lists.teachers.net
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I tried setting Eudora to use STARTTLS, SSL/TLS, and none, but they all time-out. When Eudora tries to connect, i don't see any activity in the /var/log/mail/log or /var/log/mail.err , which I guess means those aren't the relevant logs or there is no activity to report.

I haven't set up any firewall rules:

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

netstat output:

```
$ sudo netstat -tap
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:submission            *:*                     LISTEN      4112/master
tcp        0      0 *:pop3                  *:*                     LISTEN      3210/dovecot
tcp        0      0 *:imap2                 *:*                     LISTEN      3210/dovecot
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      564/sshd
tcp        0      0 *:smtp                  *:*                     LISTEN      4112/master
tcp        0      0 *:imaps                 *:*                     LISTEN      3210/dovecot
tcp        0      0 *:pop3s                 *:*                     LISTEN      3210/dovecot
tcp        0    300 lists.teachers.net:ssh  99-95-169-159.lig:55464 ESTABLISHED 1433/sshd: listman
tcp6       0      0 [::]:submission         [::]:*                  LISTEN      4112/master
tcp6       0      0 [::]:pop3               [::]:*                  LISTEN      3210/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 [::]:imap2              [::]:*                  LISTEN      3210/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      564/sshd
tcp6       0      0 [::]:smtp               [::]:*                  LISTEN      4112/master
tcp6       0      0 [::]:imaps              [::]:*                  LISTEN      3210/dovecot
tcp6       0      0 [::]:pop3s              [::]:*                  LISTEN      3210/dovecot
```

MX record:

```
$ dig mx lists.teachers.net

; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> mx lists.teachers.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 22244
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;lists.teachers.net.            IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
lists.teachers.net.     300     IN      MX      100 lists.teachers.net.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
teachers.net.           2057    IN      NS      dns1.stabletransit.com.
teachers.net.           2057    IN      NS      dns2.stabletransit.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
lists.teachers.net.     300     IN      A       50.56.184.186
dns1.stabletransit.com. 77665   IN      A       69.20.95.4
dns2.stabletransit.com. 77741   IN      A       65.61.188.4

;; Query time: 830 msec
;; SERVER: 72.3.128.241#53(72.3.128.241)
;; WHEN: Thu Jan 10 14:08:34 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 155
```

How can I troubleshoot this, maybe from a remote machine? What logs might shed light? What other info would be helpful here? Thanks!

**RESOLVED: SBC apparently blocks port 25 traffic on u-verse. I enabled port 587 in /etc/postfix/main.cf and immediately got the mail out to the server.  D'oh!**

Comment: If you have fixed your problem, please submit the fix as an answer and then accept it so that the question can be marked as having been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED: SBC apparently blocks port 25 traffic on u-verse. I enabled port 587 in /etc/postfix/main.cf and immediately got the mail out to the server. D'oh!